# SwiftUI SystemColors for Lists

Tags: colors, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a list in witch I want to highlight a selected line.
This works fine with:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
      List {
        Line(text: "Line 1")
        Line(text: "Line 2")
        Line(text: "Line 3",selected: true)
        Line(text: "Line 4")
      }
    }
}

struct Line: View {
  var text :String
  var selected = false

  var body: some View {
    Text(text)
    .listRowBackground(selected ? Color.blue : Color.white)
    .foregroundColor(selected ? Color.white : Color.black)
    }
}
```

However when switching to darkmode it looks ugly.
Ofcourse I could detect dark mode and set the color explicitly, but I am looking for a way to set the color for the "not selected" line to the standard foreground and backgroundcolor of a list.
How can I get these "Systemcolors"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to access system colors is with Color(UIColor) like this:

```
  var body: some View {
    Text(text)
    .listRowBackground(Color(.systemBackground))
    .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
    }
```

Comment: Notice this is using a UIColor conversion, Color.systemBackground which is probably what people expect to use will not compile.